# Sinon spy on all method calls

Tags: testing, coffeescript, sinon

I am trying to test whether a particular instance method has been called at least once. Using `mocha` and `sinon`. There are 2 classes: `A` and `B`. `B#render` is called inside `A#render`. There's no access to instance of `B` in a test file.

```
sinon.spy B.prototype, 'render'
@instanceA.render
B.prototype.render.called.should.equal true
B.prototype.render.restore()
```

Is this a right approach to do it?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You should do it like that:

```
const chai = require('chai');
const sinon = require('sinon');
const SinonChai = require('sinon-chai');

chai.use(SinonChai);
chai.should();

/**
 * Class A
 * @type {B}
 */
class A {

  constructor(){
      this.b = new B();
  }


  render(){
    this.b.render();
  }
}


/**
 * Class B
 * @type {[type]}
 */
class B {

  constructor(){

  }

  render(){
  }
}



context('test', function() {

  beforeEach(() => {
    if (!this.sandbox) {
      this.sandbox = sinon.sandbox.create();
    } else {
      this.sandbox.restore();
    }
  });

  it('should pass',
    (done) => {

      const a = new A();

      const spyA = this.sandbox.spy(A.prototype, 'render');
      const spyB = this.sandbox.spy(B.prototype, 'render');

      a.render();

      spyA.should.have.been.called;
      spyB.should.have.been.called;

      done();
    });

});
```

Your assumption was correct.  You add the spies at the prototype level of the class.  Hope it helps :)